# Why are bootstrap4 and font-awesome modules not recognized by webpack?

Tags: npm, webpack, npm-install, webpack-2

I am experimenting with webpack and wanted to use, among others, the `bootstrap4` and `font-awesome`. All modules are recognized except these two.

The `package.json` created after `npm install <module>`:

```
{
  "name": "blog",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "my site",
  "main": "index.html",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.25.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "bootstrap4": "0.0.1-security",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.4",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "less": "^2.7.2",
    "less-loader": "^4.0.4",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.18.2",
    "vue": "^2.3.4"
  }
}
```

The `webpack.config.js` file I use:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: path.join(__dirname, 'entry.js'),
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
        filename: 'build.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.less$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'less-loader']
            }
        ]

    }
}
```

Running `webpack` generates errors for `bootstrap4` and `font-awesome`:

```
D:\Dropbox\dev\jekyll\blog\webpack>webpack
Hash: 2501a45f8eacb5b3fdac
Version: webpack 2.7.0
Time: 3028ms
   Asset     Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
build.js  1.24 MB       0  [emitted]  [big]  main
   [0] ./~/moment/moment.js 129 kB {0} [built]
  [14] ./~/moment/locale/bo.js 3.47 kB {0} [optional] [built]
 [117] ./~/style-loader/lib/addStyles.js 8.7 kB {0} [built]
 [118] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 509 bytes {0} [built]
 [119] (webpack)/buildin/module.js 517 bytes {0} [built]
 [120] ./js/explorer.js 1.35 kB {0} [built]
 [121] ./~/lodash/lodash.js 540 kB {0} [built]
 [122] ./less/navbar.less 1.13 kB {0} [built]
 [123] ./less/style.less 1.12 kB {0} [built]
 [124] ./~/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm.js 195 kB {0} [built]
 [125] ./entry.js 572 bytes {0} [built]
 [126] ./~/css-loader!./~/less-loader/dist/cjs.js!./less/navbar.less 2.8 kB {0} [built]
 [127] ./~/css-loader!./~/less-loader/dist/cjs.js!./less/style.less 7.67 kB {0} [built]
 [128] ./~/moment/locale ^\.\/.*$ 2.79 kB {0} [optional] [built]
 [129] ./~/process/browser.js 5.42 kB {0} [built]
    + 116 hidden modules

ERROR in ./entry.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'font-awesome' in 'D:\Dropbox\dev\jekyll\blog\webpack'
 @ ./entry.js 16:0-39

ERROR in ./entry.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'bootstrap4' in 'D:\Dropbox\dev\jekyll\blog\webpack'
 @ ./entry.js 15:0-36
```

The referenced `entry.js`:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import bootstrap4 from 'bootstrap4'
import fontawesome from 'font-awesome'
import _ from 'lodash'
import moment from 'moment'
require('./less/style.less')
require('./less/navbar.less')
//require('./js/posts.js')
require('./js/explorer.js')
console.log('hello')
```

**Why are these two modules a problem?**

---

The complete error log from `webpack`, for completeness:

```
D:\Dropbox\dev\jekyll\blog\webpack>webpack --display-error-details
Hash: 2501a45f8eacb5b3fdac
Version: webpack 2.7.0
Time: 2952ms
   Asset     Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
build.js  1.24 MB       0  [emitted]  [big]  main
   [0] ./~/moment/moment.js 129 kB {0} [built]
  [14] ./~/moment/locale/bo.js 3.47 kB {0} [optional] [built]
 [117] ./~/style-loader/lib/addStyles.js 8.7 kB {0} [built]
 [118] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 509 bytes {0} [built]
 [119] (webpack)/buildin/module.js 517 bytes {0} [built]
 [120] ./js/explorer.js 1.35 kB {0} [built]
 [121] ./~/lodash/lodash.js 540 kB {0} [built]
 [122] ./less/navbar.less 1.13 kB {0} [built]
 [123] ./less/style.less 1.12 kB {0} [built]
 [124] ./~/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm.js 195 kB {0} [built]
 [125] ./entry.js 572 bytes {0} [built]
 [126] ./~/css-loader!./~/less-loader/dist/cjs.js!./less/navbar.less 2.8 kB {0} [built]
 [127] ./~/css-loader!./~/less-loader/dist/cjs.js!./less/style.less 7.67 kB {0} [built]
 [128] ./~/moment/locale ^\.\/.*$ 2.79 kB {0} [optional] [built]
 [129] ./~/process/browser.js 5.42 kB {0} [built]
    + 116 hidden modules

ERROR in ./entry.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'font-awesome' in 'D:\Dropbox\dev\jekyll\blog\webpack'
resolve 'font-awesome' in 'D:\Dropbox\dev\jekyll\blog\webpack'
  Parsed request is a module
  using description file: D:\Dropbox\dev\jekyll\blog\webpack\package.json (relative path: .)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
  after using description file: D:\Dropbox\dev\jekyll\blog\webpack\package.json (relative path: .)
    resolve as module
      D:\Dropbox\dev\jekyll\blog\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      D:\Dropbox\dev\jekyll\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      D:\Dropbox\dev\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      D:\Dropbox\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      D:\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      looking for modules in D:\Dropbox\dev\jekyll\blog\webpack\node_modules
        using description file: D:\Dropbox\dev\jekyll\blog\webpack\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        after using description file: D:\Dropbox\dev\jekyll\blog\webpack\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
          using description file: D:\Dropbox\dev\jekyll\blog\webpack\node_modules\font-awesome\package.json (relative path: .)
            no extension
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              D:\Dropbox\dev\jekyll\blog\webpack\node_modules\font-awesome is not a file
            .js
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              D:\Dropbox\dev\jekyll\blog\webpack\node_modules\font-awesome.js doesn't exist
            .json
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              D:\Dropbox\dev\jekyll\blog\webpack\node_modules\font-awesome.json doesn't exist
            as directory
              existing directory
                using path: D:\Dropbox\dev\jekyll\blog\webpack\node_modules\font-awesome\index
                  using description file: D:\Dropbox\dev\jekyll\blog\webpack\node_modules\font-awesome\package.json (relative path: ./index)
                    no extension
                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                      D:\Dropbox\dev\jekyll\blog\webpack\node_modules\font-awesome\index doesn't exist
                    .js
                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                      D:\Dropbox\dev\jekyll\blog\webpack\node_modules\font-awesome\index.js doesn't exist
                    .json
                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                      D:\Dropbox\dev\jekyll\blog\webpack\node_modules\font-awesome\index.json doesn't exist
[D:\Dropbox\dev\jekyll\blog\node_modules]
[D:\Dropbox\dev\jekyll\node_modules]
[D:\Dropbox\dev\node_modules]
[D:\Dropbox\node_modules]
[D:\node_modules]
[D:\Dropbox\dev\jekyll\blog\webpack\node_modules\font-awesome]
[D:\Dropbox\dev\jekyll\blog\webpack\node_modules\font-awesome.js]
[D:\Dropbox\dev\jekyll\blog\webpack\node_modules\font-awesome.json]
[D:\Dropbox\dev\jekyll\blog\webpack\node_modules\font-awesome\index]
[D:\Dropbox\dev\jekyll\blog\webpack\node_modules\font-awesome\index.js]
[D:\Dropbox\dev\jekyll\blog\webpack\node_modules\font-awesome\index.json]
 @ ./entry.js 16:0-39

ERROR in ./entry.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'bootstrap4' in 'D:\Dropbox\dev\jekyll\blog\webpack'
resolve 'bootstrap4' in 'D:\Dropbox\dev\jekyll\blog\webpack'
  Parsed request is a module
  using description file: D:\Dropbox\dev\jekyll\blog\webpack\package.json (relative path: .)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
  after using description file: D:\Dropbox\dev\jekyll\blog\webpack\package.json (relative path: .)
    resolve as module
      D:\Dropbox\dev\jekyll\blog\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      D:\Dropbox\dev\jekyll\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      D:\Dropbox\dev\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      D:\Dropbox\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      D:\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      looking for modules in D:\Dropbox\dev\jekyll\blog\webpack\node_modules
        using description file: D:\Dropbox\dev\jekyll\blog\webpack\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        after using description file: D:\Dropbox\dev\jekyll\blog\webpack\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
          using description file: D:\Dropbox\dev\jekyll\blog\webpack\node_modules\bootstrap4\package.json (relative path: .)
            no extension
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              D:\Dropbox\dev\jekyll\blog\webpack\node_modules\bootstrap4 is not a file
            .js
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              D:\Dropbox\dev\jekyll\blog\webpack\node_modules\bootstrap4.js doesn't exist
            .json
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              D:\Dropbox\dev\jekyll\blog\webpack\node_modules\bootstrap4.json doesn't exist
            as directory
              existing directory
                use ./index.js from main in package.json
                  using description file: D:\Dropbox\dev\jekyll\blog\webpack\node_modules\bootstrap4\package.json (relative path: .)
                    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                  after using description file: D:\Dropbox\dev\jekyll\blog\webpack\node_modules\bootstrap4\package.json (relative path: .)
                    using description file: D:\Dropbox\dev\jekyll\blog\webpack\node_modules\bootstrap4\package.json (relative path: ./index.js)
                      no extension
                        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                        D:\Dropbox\dev\jekyll\blog\webpack\node_modules\bootstrap4\index.js doesn't exist
                      .js
                        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                        D:\Dropbox\dev\jekyll\blog\webpack\node_modules\bootstrap4\index.js.js doesn't exist
                      .json
                        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                        D:\Dropbox\dev\jekyll\blog\webpack\node_modules\bootstrap4\index.js.json doesn't exist
                      as directory
                        D:\Dropbox\dev\jekyll\blog\webpack\node_modules\bootstrap4\index.js doesn't exist
                using path: D:\Dropbox\dev\jekyll\blog\webpack\node_modules\bootstrap4\index
                  using description file: D:\Dropbox\dev\jekyll\blog\webpack\node_modules\bootstrap4\package.json (relative path: ./index)
                    no extension
                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                      D:\Dropbox\dev\jekyll\blog\webpack\node_modules\bootstrap4\index doesn't exist
                    .js
                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                      D:\Dropbox\dev\jekyll\blog\webpack\node_modules\bootstrap4\index.js doesn't exist
                    .json
                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                      D:\Dropbox\dev\jekyll\blog\webpack\node_modules\bootstrap4\index.json doesn't exist
[D:\Dropbox\dev\jekyll\blog\node_modules]
[D:\Dropbox\dev\jekyll\node_modules]
[D:\Dropbox\dev\node_modules]
[D:\Dropbox\node_modules]
[D:\node_modules]
[D:\Dropbox\dev\jekyll\blog\webpack\node_modules\bootstrap4]
[D:\Dropbox\dev\jekyll\blog\webpack\node_modules\bootstrap4.js]
[D:\Dropbox\dev\jekyll\blog\webpack\node_modules\bootstrap4.json]
[D:\Dropbox\dev\jekyll\blog\webpack\node_modules\bootstrap4\index.js]
[D:\Dropbox\dev\jekyll\blog\webpack\node_modules\bootstrap4\index.js.js]
[D:\Dropbox\dev\jekyll\blog\webpack\node_modules\bootstrap4\index.js.json]
[D:\Dropbox\dev\jekyll\blog\webpack\node_modules\bootstrap4\index.js]
[D:\Dropbox\dev\jekyll\blog\webpack\node_modules\bootstrap4\index]
[D:\Dropbox\dev\jekyll\blog\webpack\node_modules\bootstrap4\index.js]
[D:\Dropbox\dev\jekyll\blog\webpack\node_modules\bootstrap4\index.json]
 @ ./entry.js 15:0-36
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`font-awesome` does not have any [fields in `package.json`](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/blob/3a2fab89c4dcf2a049a4605a313fb34ce5a37465/package.json#L5) that are [recognised by webpack](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-mainfields) and there is also [no `index.js` in the package](https://unpkg.com/font-awesome@4.7.0/), therefore it can't be imported as usual. Presumably you want to use the CSS file, so you could import it like this.

```
import 'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css';
```

`bootstrap4` is not a real package. From the [npm registry - `bootstrap4`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap4):

> ## Security holding package
>
> This package name is not currently in use, but was formerly occupied by another package. To avoid malicious use, npm is hanging on to the package name, but loosely, and we'll probably give it to you if you want it.
>
> You may adopt this package by contacting support@npmjs.com and requesting the name.

You need the actual [`boostrap` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap). The stable version is currently  `3.3.7`, but the v4 alpha is available on npm. You can install it with:

```
npm install --save bootstrap@next
```

Comment: Both your initial assertions are mostly correct. s/recognized by webpack/recognized by default by webpack/. You can modify `resolve.mainFields`. Just read my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed make font-awesome work nicely with webpack. Add the element `"style"` to `resolve.mainFields`:

```
module.exports = {

  ...

  resolve: {
    ...
    mainFields: ["browser", "module", "main", "style"]
    ...
  }

  ...
}
```

The first three values come from the [docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-mainfields), and the last one comes from [the `font-awesome` `package.json`](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/blob/master/package.json) field:

```
{
  ...
  "style": "css/font-awesome.css",
  ...
}
```

Now webpack knows where font-awesome keeps its CSS! Do keep in mind that webpack will set a default value for `resolve.mainFields` based on the webpack config field `target`; This change negates this behavior, so you'll have to read the [docs](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/targets/) for the correct `resolve.mainField` values.